# Is this definition for a strictly triangular system from my textbook incorrect?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, definition

Definition from my textbook (Linear Algebra with Applications by Steven J. Leon, 9edg):

> A system is said to be in **strict triangular form** if , in the $k$th equation, the coefficients of the first $k-1$ variables are all zero and the coefficient of $x_k$ is nonzero $(k = 1,\dots,n)$.

This says that the entries along the diagonal are nonzero.

However, [wikipedia defines it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#strictly-triangular-matrix) as:

> If all of the entries on the main diagonal of a (upper or lower) triangular matrix are also 0, the matrix is called strictly (upper or lower) triangular.

This says that the entries along the diagonal must be zero

Which is the correct definition, and why?

Comment: They're different things. Note that a strictly triangular form ensures a non-zero diagonal but the zero matrix is strictly upper triangular.

Comment: @CyclotomicField How are they two different things? They are both describing strictly triangular matrices.

Comment: The zero matrix is not a strictly triangular form because it has entries on the diagonal that are zero. This is because $x_k \neq 0$ is part of the definition.

Comment: @CyclotomicField So you are saying that the Wikipedia definition is incorrect?

Comment: (Upper/Lower) Triangular: No entries (Below/Above) the diagonal.. Strictly Triangular: (Upper/Lower) Triangular and also, diagonal is zero.

Comment: @DavidP so the textbook definition is incorrect?

Comment: I'm saying that they're different definitions for different things. Both definitions are correct you're just confused. A strictly triangular form requires a full diagonal of non-zero numbers. Strictly upper triangular matrices do not require this. They're different things.

Comment: Nevertheless, if this is a course you are in stick to THOSE definitions.

Comment: @DavidP As I read it, the definition requires only that diagonal entries be non-zero and below-diagonal entries be zero (so it is an upper triangular system). Above-diagonal entries are not specified and could be zero or non-zero.

Comment: @DavidK Yes, I misread (variables vs coefficients). Still it seems the textbook's version is what most other sources call just upper triangular.

Answer (score 1):

If a system of equations like
$$
a_1 x_{1} + a_2 x_{2}  = 0\\
b_1 x_1 + b_2 x_2 = 0
$$
was "strictly upper triangular" like the matrix,
that would just mean that $a_1=b_1=b_2=0$ so it would just mean that one of the variables, in the above example $x_2$, was unused, and you'd go straight back to a system with one less variable and non-zero diagonal entries, so that would be a meaningless definition.

Your textbook's definition is the only meaningful one it's possible to make.